# rails order by time with reversed 24 hour periods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model which stores events which each have a start time.

The start time is handled by rails as Time, but stored in Postgres as datetime (I'm assuming) and rails just ignores the date and stores it as 2000-01-01...

The problem I have is ordering it so that events that start after midnight show up afterwards and not before.  How can I sort them differently and split events in the 24 hour period so that the first morning 12 hour events show up after the second half of evening events. (if that makes since)

Any ideas?

```
c=Event.last
c.event_items.order(:time_start)
```

which does ORDER BY \"event_items\".time_start ASC"

```
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id  | event_id | artist_id | time_start              | area_id | created_at              | updated_at              |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 155 | 63       | 111       | 2000-01-01 00:40:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-24 21:21:57 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
| 153 | 63       | 133       | 2000-01-01 01:10:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-24 21:21:57 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
| 152 | 63       | 128       | 2000-01-01 02:00:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-24 21:21:57 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
| 151 | 63       | 148       | 2000-01-01 22:10:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-24 21:21:57 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
| 194 | 63       | 124       | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
| 154 | 63       | 98        | 2000-01-01 23:50:00 UTC |         | 2013-08-24 21:21:57 UTC | 2013-08-26 00:07:44 UTC |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I would like the dates to from before 12h (24h clock) to come after those 12h+...

eg in this example I would like the order to be 22:10, 23:00, 23:50, 00:40, 01:10, 02:00

Comment: so do you want them to be sorted in a way so that they appear in a order of occurrence with the current time?

Comment: I dont understand, whats your question, Im sorry!

Comment: @holden I answered to best of my understanding, did I understand you correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [date_part](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function in postgres so I think you could do something like this

```
Event.order("CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)/12 DESC,
             CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)%12 ASC")
```

If you want to divide your time in different modular then try with different divider.

**UPDATE**

I guess I need to elaborate a bit.

Basically I extract the *hour* part of `time_start` **timestamp** and convert (or `cast`) it to **integer** as I want to work with **integer** not **time**. If we simply divide *hour* by 12 it will give us an interval, have a look on the link to postgres doc above for more details.

So the first expression `CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)/12` give us either *0* or *1*; *0* if *hour* is before *12* and *1* for *12* onwards. This does what you want, put hours after *12* on top of hours after *12*. They will be sorted from 23 > 12, then 11 > 0 though, so not exactly what you want.

Hence the second `CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)%12`. This will give use *23* => *11*, *22* => *10* ... *12* => *0* and *11* => *11* ... *0* => *0* etc. So we can sort them in ascending order.

By the way, this doesn't sort *minutes* so you may want to add `time_start ASC` as a third sort criteria. I think you could also add `CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)` to `SELECT` statement and name it then only refer to that name on `ORDER BY`.

Hope this help :)

Comment: One last question, I'm confused how would I add the minutes as the third criteria?

Comment: just add `time_start ASC` to the mix so it would be `CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)/12 DESC, CAST(date_part('hour', time_start) AS Integer)%12 ASC, time_start ASC`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do it like that

```
c = Event.where(:time_start > 12.hours).order(:time_start) << Event.where(:time_start < 12.hours).order(:time_start)
```

this will concatenate the two results one after the other and give you the desired result.

Comment: The time comparison of >= doesn't work.  "ArgumentError: comparison of Symbol with ActiveSupport::Duration failed" but I was also hoping there was a cleaner way to do it with an order by clause.  ;-)

Comment: @holden okay thanks for the correction, but I hope you got the idea of my answer.

Comment: It's a small effort to update this to the correct syntax, so please do that instead of leaving a comment like that.